# PromQL Union operator omitting __metric__ label

Tags: prometheus, promql

I am doing a union operation on two datapoints.

```
database_bootstrapping{instance="host1",job="db"}!=0.   no data
absent(database_bootstrapping{instance="host1",job="db"}).
```

Query is

```
database_bootstrapping{instance="host1",job="db"}!=0 or absent(database_bootstrapping{instance="host1",job="db"})
```

Result is

```
{instance="host1",job="db"}.   1
```

What I want is

```
database_bootstrapping{instance="host1",job="db"}   1
```

How can I retain the ____metric____ label name in the query output?

Answer (score 1):

https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#label_replace

```
label_replace(database_bootstrapping{instance="host1",job="db"}!=0 or absent(database_bootstrapping{instance="host1",job="db"}), "__name", "database_bootstrapping")
```